# How to execute IronPython script in separate thread and then suspend it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, ironpython, scheduling

Lets assume I have such code for testing.

```
public class SimpleScheduler
{
    public Script Script { get; set; }

    private Thread _worker;

    public void Schedule()
    {
        this._worker = new Thread(this.Script.Execute);
        this._worker.Start();
    }

    public void Sleep()
    {
        //?
    }
}
```

`SimpleScheduler` just takes `Script` object and tries to execute it in separate thread.

```
    public class Script
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        private ScriptSource _scriptSource;

        private ScriptScope _scope;

        private CompiledCode _code;

        private string source = @"import clr
clr.AddReference('Trampoline')
from Trampoline import PythonCallBack
def Start():
   PythonCallBack.Sleep()";

        public Script()
        {
            _scriptSource = IronPythonHelper.IronPythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(this.source);
            _scope = IronPythonHelper.IronPythonEngine.CreateScope();
            _code = _scriptSource.Compile();
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _code.Execute(_scope);
            dynamic start = _scope.GetVariable("Start");
            start();
        }
    }
```

`Script` class tries to callback Sleep function of `PythonCallBack` class and wants to be suspended for some time.

```
public static class PythonCallBack
{
    public static SimpleScheduler Scheduler;

    static PythonCallBack()
    {
        Scheduler = new SimpleScheduler();
    }

    public static void Sleep()
    {
        Scheduler.Sleep();
    }
}
```

PythonCallBack just for calling sleep method of SimpleScheduler.

Question:
What is the best way to suspend thread, which executes Script? and then how to resume this thread execution?

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread` class has a `Suspend()` and `Resume()` method. These methods suspend and resume the thread. Even though there is a warning concerning this method, this should not be a problem because you are suspending at a known location.

An alternative is to use events. You can give the `Script` or `ScriptScope` class a `AutoResetEvent`. Then, in the `Sleep()`, you call `WaitOne()` on the event. Then, from the outside, when you want the thread to resume, you call `Set()`.

Comment: Suspend() and Resume() methods are deprecated and unsafe for threads synchronization